# В чем разница между CLI и CLS

Tags: .net, clr, консоль

Чем отличается CLI(Common Language Infrastructure) от CLS(Common Language Specification)?

Comment: [CLI (англ. Common Language Infrastructure) — спецификация общеязыковой инфраструктуры.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure)

Answer (score 4):

[CLI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) – это спецификация платформы для CIL (и C#) кода, т. е. библиотеки для работы языка, прописанные в стандарте.

[CLS](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/CLS_(Common_Language_Specification)) – это спецификация самого языка. Она нужна для совместимости всех языков, работающих на одной платформе, чтобы интерфейс кода работал для любого языка.

[CLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) – это просто реализация CLI.

Comment: CLS спецификация ЯП или промежуточного языка?

Comment: @n_enrai49 спецификация ЯП, т. к. CIL сам по себе CLS-совместим

Comment: `cls` — это `clear` ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor точно) точнее CLear Screen

Comment: a `cli` — `command line` ;)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112157/room-for-victor-vosmottor-and-return

Comment: @return, по поводу описания метки [tag:cli], которое вы добавили недавно. В вопросах по данной метке я вижу в основном cli в смысле Command Line Interface. Всего 50 вопросов с этой меткой, и только 5 сообщений (вопросов или ответов) с упоминанием [Common Language Infrastructure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Common+Language+Infrastructure). Мне кажется, лучше создать для Common Language Infrastructure отдельную метку.

Comment: @insolor согласен! надо над этим поработать